# Visual Studio creates bin folder on opening web application solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio is creating a \bin folder and copying various assemblies into it when I open a web application solution, even before I compile

What is triggering this action?

And how do I control it?

Reason I'm questioning the process, is the assemblies are not the expected ones

Comment: If you're using Nuget, could it be that that's getting the DLLs you need?

Comment: Web projects automatically create this, what assemblies exactly are unexpected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where Visual Studio puts all the dlls for runtime for your project. Library dependencies that the project needs. All the dlls that Visual Studio needs for a web project are kept here as well as other packages from Nuget that you might add, and your own. If you look in the References section in the Web Project, you will see many of the dlls that appear in the bin directory.

If there are some assemblies there that you do not want. You can try removing the reference from the Reference folder. Right click on the library in the Reference folder and select remove.

Be careful with removing references though, because your project may need it to function.